# How to translate "leach" (as in "toxic chemicals leach into ground water")?

Tags: translation

For example:

> It's not safe to drink from PVC pipes, because PVC can leak poisons into the water.
>
> Fracking can cause toxic chemicals to leach into ground water.

The translation I found was `滤去`, but `滤` means to filter, so I'm not sure if that's the proper translation.

Comment: You need to consider "leach into" instead of just "leach". I would use "渗入" It means seeped / penetrate. It is perfectly fine to say 渗入水中

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at what Chinese website say about fracking, you can see for example:

[PetroChina](http://wap.cnpc.com.cn/system/2015/06/09/001545481.shtml):

> 报告认为，水力压裂可能出现的危险在于在压裂过程中可能出现液体溢出，压裂直接渗透到地下水资源中以及对废水的不当处理和排放等方面。

So CNPC uses `渗透` to say that the chemicals get into the ground water.

As for your other example regarding [PVC](http://www.cbda.cn/html/jczixun/20140404/39411.html):

> 生物污染主要是由于管材氧渗透和透光使管内的水介质滋生细菌；化学性污染主要来自于管道接触材料的渗透。

Again they use `渗透` to indicate how the chemicals/bacterial get into the water.

Note: As the comments note, some other ways you  might say this could include `渗入` and `进入`.

Comment: +1 for 滲入 is very common